# Math.js expression syntax

Tags: math.js

How do you enter a power root in Math.js' expression syntax? In AsciiMath I can enter "-root(3)(x+4)-4". How can I get the same result in the expression syntax of Math.js?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SjzV.png)

Comment: I think the docs say:  `-nthRoot(x+4,3)-4`   (see: https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/nthRoot.html )

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to write a live code to answer the question. And it is

```
-nthRoot(x+4,3)-4
```

as commented by @Luuk.

```js
// Use this function to show values of matrix and etc.
function print (value) {
  const precision = 14
  console.log(math.format(value, precision))
}
print("Start MathJS test.")
//print(math.round(math.e, 3))     // 2.718
let x = 23
print( -math.nthRoot(x+4,3) -4 )   // -7
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/11.3.1/math.js"></script>
```